# How to run vscode extension command just right after installation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to run the extension command right after the installation. There is an event like `onStartupFinished`, but the problem is, it will run every time the vscode starts.
How to do it? does vsocde have any way to do it?

Comment: Thanks to Mike's answer, here is a working [example](https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon/tpack/blob/master/src/util.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a version field in the global context state. You get the context in your activation method.

```js
export const activate = (context: ExtensionContext): void => {
    const myExtension = extensions.getExtension("<my-extension-id>");
    const currentVersion = myExtension!.packageJSON.version ?? "1.0.0";

    const lastVersion = context.globalState.get("MyExtensionVersion");
    if (currentVersion !== lastVersion) {
        void context.globalState.update("MyExtensionVersion", currentVersion);
        // Do one time setup here.
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set `onStartupFinished` in `activationEvents`.